# Error formating the date- The date is not a valid date

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I have a form where I can select some posts using radio buttons and after select some post the info of that post is populated in some form fields below and then the user can update the fields and click in "update".

One form field is a date field. And Im using datetimepicker. In the input I want to show the date  after select the date using datetimepicker on this format:
"10 Abril 2018 - 00:24"

The issue is that the date appears like "Th 02 yyyy - 06:ii".

And then when the update button is clicked it appears a validation error "The ticket type start date is not a valid date.".

Do you know where is the issue?

**I have this html input:**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="date">Date</label>
    <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
        <input type='text' onkeydown="event.preventDefault()"
               name="date" value="{{old('date')}}"
               class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYY" />
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
  $( ".input-group.date" ).datetimepicker({
    format: "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii",
    autoclose: true,
    todayBtn: true,
    minuteStep: 5
});

...            
// some jquery to load the form fields with some values when the correspondend radio button is selected    
 $("input[name='date']").val( moment(data.date).format('dd MM yyyy - hh:ii'));
```

**Then the controller:**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
        //dd($request->date);
        //dd($request->all());

        $this->validate($request, [
            'date' => 'required|date',

        ]);

        $postToUpdate = Post::find($request->radiobutton);
        ....
        $postToUpdate->date = $request->date;

        $postToUpdate->save();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Comment: What's the output of `dd($request->date)`?

Comment: Im not understanding but its appearing like "YYYY-November-Tuesday 01:11:00" if I update the date field. If I dont update, that is, if I select a post and then click in update without updating any field it appears ""2018-03-02 - 12:30:00".

Comment: When appears like this ""2018-03-02 - 12:30:00" the validation error dont appears, but like that is not possible to update the date field.

Comment: mysql datetime format is 2018-02-11 23:28:45, and you are giving it a date with  letters

Comment: Your JavaScript formatting is off. I just tried `moment(new Date()).format('dd MM yyyy - hh:ii')` and it returns `Mo 04 yyyy - 07:ii`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Carbon from your controller

```
echo Carbon::create(2000, 1, 35, 13, 0, 0); // 2000-02-04 13:00:00
echo Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H', '1975-05-21 22')->toDateTimeString(); // 1975-05-21 22:00:00
```

For more examples check here http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

It will format your date correctly for you to update your database.

Try this too - Not sure but might work

```
$( ".input-group.date" ).datetimepicker({
    format: "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii",
    autoclose: true,
    todayBtn: true,
    minuteStep: 5
});
```